# Bind multiple events in node-hound?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-watcher

I am using node-hound as a directory watcher.

```js
hound = require('hound');

watcher = hound.watch('/dir');

watcher.on('create', function(file) {
  console.log('hello');
});
watcher.on('change', function(file) {
  console.log('hello');
});
```

How can I bind together the `create` and the `change` events assuming that the callback function will perform the exact same task? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare only a single function and pass that to both `on` calls:

```
const hound = require('hound');

function hello(file) {
  console.log('hello');
}
const watcher = hound.watch('/dir');
watcher.on('create', hello);
watcher.on('change', hello);
```